# How to have a VLookup in the same worksheet in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have the following Excel data:

```
    A          B           C
1 asdasd    asdasd     VLOOKUP("fg",$A$1:$A$11,2,FALSE)
2 asdasd    dfgd
3 asdasd    fghfgh
4 asdasd    tryrty
5 asdasd    456456
6 asdasd    45456
7 asdasd    456456
8 fgddgh    46fgtfgh
9 fghfgh    46456
10 dfgdfg   456546
11 fghfgh   456456
```

In the `C` column, I am getting a `#N/A`

What I am looking to achieve is if `fg` is in column A, show me the value of column B in column C.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Do you want to match any instance of `fg` (e.g. dfgdfg` is a match) or only when the entry in column A is `fg`?

Comment: ONLY fg and nothing else :)

Comment: In that case you will always get `#N/A` as per your examples in column A as none of them are ONLY `fg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bracket your vlookup with if(iserror(vlookup()   ), "", vlookup())

so

=if(iserror(VLOOKUP("fg",$A$1:$B$11,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP("fg",$A$1:$B$11,2,FALSE))

Basically if it can't find fg, it throws an error.  The if( iserror()) says if you get an error, return blank cell.  If there's no error, (fg exists), return column 2.

In your current table, this function will return "" for all lines since none of them = "fg".  If you want anything that contains, you can use wild cards someone else mentioned but it sounds like you want exact hits.

Comment: As someone else mentioned, you also can't reference column 2 if your lookup area is only 1 width.  So to return the column 2 value, you need to widen the look range to $A$1:$B$11.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change to

```
VLOOKUP("fg",$A$1:$B$11,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: I used that for cell C and I still get a `#N/A`

Comment: I used this for the first row: =VLOOKUP("*fg*",A1:B11,2,FALSE) and the result is 46fgtfgh

Answer (score 0):

You get `#N/A` because `"fg"` in the `VLOOKUP` is searching for an exact match (i.e. "fg") and there isn't one in your column A.

Instead use a **wildcard**. Examples:

```
=VLOOKUP("fg",A2:B11,2,FALSE) //gets exact match

=VLOOKUP("*fg",A2:B11,2,FALSE) //matches when `fg` at the end e.g. `aaaafg`

=VLOOKUP("fg*",A2:B11,2,FALSE) //matches when `fg` at the start e.g. `fgaaaa`

=VLOOKUP("*fg*",A2:B11,2,FALSE) //matches when `fg` found in the entry e.g. `aafgaa`
```

Comment: I used this for the first row: `=VLOOKUP("*fg*",A1:B11,2,FALSE)` and the result is `46fgtfgh`

Comment: I would like to do for each A1 and B1, A2 and B2, etc. etc.

Comment: I changed to this: `=VLOOKUP("*fg*",$A$1:$B$11,1,FALSE)` and I keep getting `fgddgh` which is from A8/

Comment: Yes because that is the first match that the VLOOKUP finds for `*fg* in column A. What result are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: Column C should display nothing is column A doesn't have a match, and display the value from column B if there is a match.

Comment: But what is a match? `fg` will only match `fg`. `*fg` will match `aaaafg`, `bbbbfg` etc.

Comment: As long as there is a FG in the column A, why I used *fg*?

Comment: To be clear, you want `fgddgh` to be a match correct?